Search for (part of) a table column name in an SQL Server Database using Dbeaver UI search function
I need to look into a SQL Server database and find a column for BI purposes.
I found the DBeaver Metadata search function (Ctrl+H), and on a PostGreSQL server I can see "Table Column" as a possible object to search.
However, the database I need to search is SQL Server, and there is no "Table Column" object there to search in. If I want to search the whole database for columns that contain for instance "%suppress%" in the column name, how do I go about it? Specifically using UI, not a SQL statement.

I tried using the DBeaver Metadata search and expected to have an object "Table Column" there. In reality, there is no Table Column object. The search for "%Suppress%" yielded no results although there are at least to table columns that have "suppress" in their name.

Does this answer your question? Find all tables containing column with specified name

@siggemannen No, it doesn't, I am looking for a solution using the DBeaver UI.

You wrote preferably. It's anyway better to learn some SQL, this is not a DBeaver support forum.

"I need to search is SQL Server, and there is no "Table Column" object" Yes there is, sys.columns. There's also, unsurprisingly, sys.tables, sys.views, sys.schemas, etc, etc...

@siggemannen Yes, you're right, I'll edit the question and leave out the preferably, and specify better that I am looking for a UI solution.

@ThomA I see what you mean, but in the search UI in DBeaver there is no Table Column object, and that's my problem.

Maybe DBeaver doesn't have such a feature. But the feature is there in SQL Server, and can be queried regardless of what tool you are using; SSMS, DBeaver, ADS, sqlcmd, etc, etc.

It seems that DBeaver does not have this feature.
See the comment by TheMechanist902, Apr. 16, 2024 on DBeaver Github Issue "Add column name object in the metadata search for Oracle databases" (#8684).

I recently noticed this feature is not available for MSSQL either.
However I found a workaround that is independent from the used DBMS.
By displaying the ERD diagram you can search the diagram for any
string. This includes columns names. It's a bit clunky, but better
than nothing.
Of course this isn't a real replacement for a proper search feature,
but maybe it helps in a pinch. Theoretically you can search inside an
exported graphml file as well.

